# pam_systemd delays SSH login - required?

Tags: ssh, login, ldap, pam, systemd

On our Saucy servers (13.10) we are seeing long delays when logging into the systems via SSH.
I figured out it is related to the line

```
session optional        pam_systemd.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`.

When I comment that line, login is immediate.

The `/var/log/auth.log` output that accompanies any delayed login attempts looks like this:

```
May 21 17:33:58 control02 sshd[18488]: Accepted publickey for daniel.schneller from 10.102.2.9 port 35763 ssh2
May 21 17:33:58 control02 sshd[18488]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user daniel.schneller by (uid=0)
May 21 17:34:23 control02 sshd[18488]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

I could not find any definite documentation yet whether or not I need the module at all. I could, of course, leave it commented out, because it seems to only wait for a timeout anyway at the moment, but I would rather understand the underlying cause and fix that, if at all possible, to prevent problems down the road.

Comment: The `libpam-systemd` package is installed by default on desktop systems but I think not on server installs. Is this a desktop or server install? Are the `dbus` and `systemd-logind` upstart jobs running? Does the SSH login get a valid logind session? The timeout seems like a dbus timeout communicating with logind.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Debian Jessie 8 and found another solution here:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=770135#46

The command 
`systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`
or a complete reboot fixed the ssh login delay for me.